# Extracting attribute data to points

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff-tiff, attribute-table

I have a GeoTIFF file downloaded from: https://www.fao.org/soils-portal/soil-survey/soil-maps-and-databases/harmonized-world-soil-database-v12/en/

It includes ".tif" and ".dbf", so it has the attribute table. I want to use Python (gdal, rasterio, xarray, ...) to extract the values to points that each point includes the attribute data instead of just the raster values. How do I do it?

I took a demo data from the whole data: [select_data](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ms77CpidK7gMu24KSx4XW1bJpwCFOH4k?usp=sharing)

[image]
The attribute table in GeoTIFF, the black triangles are the points to be extracted.

Using "extract values to points" in ArcGIS, I can only get the raster value, but not the attribute content.
[image]

Comment: You can join the tables on `RASTERVALU = MU_GLOBAL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your example

Read the points shapefile

```
import numpy as np
import geopandas as gpd
points = gpd.read_file("points.shp")
# coordinates of the points shapefile
coords = np.stack((points.geometry.x, points.geometry.y), axis=1)
print(coords)
[[-116.34337335   39.45057669]
[-116.16491378   38.45834145]
[-115.44869601   39.19597436]]
```

Read the raster attribute table (dbf file to pandas DataFrame)

```
from simpledbf import Dbf5 
import pandas as pd
dbf = Dbf5("image.tif.vat.dbf")
rastat = dbf.to_dataframe()
print(rastat.Value) # key
0    5072
1    5090
2    5091
Name: Value, dtype: int64
```

Read the raster file

```
import rasterio as rio
raster  = rio.open("image.tif")
```

Extract raster values at coords

```
points["Value"] = [sample[0] for sample in raster.sample(coords)]
print(points)
   Id           geometry            Value
0   0  POINT (-116.34337 39.45058)   5072
1   0  POINT (-116.16491 38.45834)   5091
2   0  POINT (-115.44870 39.19597)   5090
```

Join the GeoDataFrame and the DataFrame on "Value"

```
points  = points.merge(rastat, on='Value')
print(points)
   Id          geometry            Value  ...    S_CASO4  S_ESP  S_ECE
0   0  POINT (-116.34337 39.45058)   5072  ...      0.7    5.0    3.8
1   0  POINT (-116.16491 38.45834)   5091  ...      0.7    4.0    9.7
2   0  POINT (-115.44870 39.19597)   5090  ...      0.7    4.0    9.7
```

Save the resulting shapefile

```
points.to_file("result.shp")
```